# How can I disable the inversion of the order of a string copied from a pdf generated with headless Chrome?

Tags: macos, chromium, preview, headless

Generating pdfs with Chrome in headless mode seems to affect the order of characters when copying strings from the pdf.

To reproduce the issue:

`chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=example.pdf https://www.example.com/`

or

`chrome --headless=new --print-to-pdf=example.pdf https://www.example.com/`

[image]

Then open `example.pdf`, select all content and paste it in a word processor.

```
5/18/23, 5:26 PM Example Domain
  https://www.example.com/
1/1
.noissimrep rof gniksa ro noitanidrooc roirp tuohtiw erutaretil ni niamod siht esu yam uoY .stnemucod ni selpmaxe evitartsulli ni esu rof si niamod sihT
...noitamrofni eroM
niamoD elpmaxE
```

Interestingly, the header and footer strings don’t seem to be affected...

Playwright, Puppeteer Chrome and Chromium all yield the same results.

I couldn’t find any documentation addressing the issue.

How can I disable this behavior?

OS: macOS 11.7.6, Big Sur
Region: Netherlands
Language preferences: Dutch, French, English

**Edit 19 May 2023**

Seems to be a [known](https://forum.obsidian.md/t/exported-pdf-on-macos-produces-backward-text-with-copy-paste/50998/15) Preview.app bug.